# Can LVM split files between volumes?

Tags: files, lvm

Let's say I have 2 volumes 2 GB each (kept as single group). And I would copy there 3GB file.

Will it be split?

*I just hope the answer is "no", and the files are atomic. The reason is -- with guarantee "no split", it is possible to mount single volume, and copy files to another one.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVM can split file under multiple volume, and in some case it's a needed comportement.

LVM work as physical part, just upper partitioning shemas, consequently it's filesystem agnostic and don't know the concept of file that managed by filesystem.

To convince youi better, LVM is capable of make agregation like RAID0 does, xKbites from the first disk, next to the second, ...

Comment: Bad news for my case, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

LVM doesn't know anything about files. It provides a big block of storage. It's up to the filesystem to organize this block to store files, and the filesystem doesn't know (nor want to care) about which files are on which physical volume.

Even if a file is entirely contained in one physical volume (which for most filesystems is guaranteed if the file is small enough — less than the filesystem's block size, which is typically in the 512B–4kB range), you still wouldn't be able to mount just that physical volume and see the file. You can't mount an arbitrary chunk of a filesystem. The indications of which file is stored where are not stored at the same location as the file itself; to reach a file, you need to traverse the directory chain down to the file, and there is additional metadata (most unix filesystems have an inode table) which is necessary to retrieve any data.

If you want a guarantee regarding which file is on which disk, put the disks in different volume groups. Or at least, create different logical volumes (you can shuffle LVs between PVs with `pvmove`).